# Spring Boot h2 initial data not creating table first

Tags: spring-boot, initialization, h2

I am trying to create a small Spring Boot setup with a h2 database.

Now I have a weird problem, which I can't solve.
If I don't create an `data.sql` for initial data, the app starts fine and creates my entity tables.
If I create an `data.sql` for initial data and keep the existing table from previous step, everything works fine.
If I create an `data.sql` for initial data and remove my existing h2 file, I get the error that it can't import the data, because the table is missing.

How do I tell Spring to create my tables before importing the initial data?

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using and are you using Hibernate in your app?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I am using the latest version 2.5.1 and I have the hibernate dependency and only using it for `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [covered](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5-Release-Notes#hibernate-and-datasql) in the release notes for Spring Boot 2.5:

> By default, `data.sql` scripts are now run before Hibernate is initialized. This aligns the behavior of basic script-based initialization with that of Flyway and Liquibase. If you want to use `data.sql` to populate a schema created by Hibernate, set `spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization` to `true`. While mixing database initialization technologies is not recommended, this will also allow you to use a `schema.sql` script to build upon a Hibernate-created schema before it’s populated via `data.sql`.